# Where am I loading jquery_ujs in my Rails 6 app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ujs

Bugsnag is reporting this error on many pages: **"If you load both jquery_ujs and rails-ujs, use rails-ujs only"**

Rails 6.1.3, with webpacker.

**application.js:**

```
//
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**_head.html.erb:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule="" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

<script src="//d2wy8f7a9ursnm.cloudfront.net/v7/bugsnag.min.js"></script>

<script>
  <% if current_user.blank? %>
    var currentUser = null;

    Bugsnag.start(
    { 
      apiKey: '<%= BUGSNAG_API_KEY %>', 
      releaseStage: '<%= Rails.env %>'
    });

  <% else %>
    var currentUser = { email: '<%= current_user.email %>' };

    Bugsnag.start(
    { 
      apiKey: '<%= BUGSNAG_API_KEY %>', 
      releaseStage: '<%= Rails.env %>',
      user: { email: '<%= current_user.email %>' }
    });
  <% end %>
</script>


<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => 'reload' %>
```

I've looked but cannot find jQuery UJS in my code. So why am I getting this error? And how could I remove it? I can't reproduce it, and cannot tell if this is breaking the UX or is a warning.

Thanks.

Comment: do you see it loading in dev tools, either network or sources panel?

Comment: when this happened to me, I found it in vendor/assets/javascripts/. You could do a `find . -type f -name 'jquery.*'`

Comment: I looked as you suggested. `find` doesn't return any instance of `jquery*` or `*ujs*` being included, as expected.

Comment: I checked both prod and dev, neither show existence of jquery-ujs. Only rails-ujs is loaded and shows up in source and network tabs. I used the search function to look if jquery_ujs was being loaded as part of another js lib, it isn't.

Comment: maybe there's no problem... the message says "if you load... etc" maybe it's just information!